# Automatically update the XML file, without refresh page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

Automatically update the XML file, No entries and error to display..

XML File;

```
 <programme channel="cnn.info" start="20131021000000" stop="20131021010000">
 <title>CNN Newsroom live from Hong Kong</title>
 <premiere/></programme>

 <programme channel="cnn.info" start="20131021010000" stop="20131021020000">
 <title>CNN Newsroom live from Hong Kong</title>
 <premiere/></programme>

 <programme channel="cnn.info" start="20131021020000" stop="20131021023000">
 <title>BackStory</title>
```

Javascript Codes;

```
   <![CDATA[
    var autoUpdate, xmlData, loadXMLData, update, eventsXML;
    update = function() {
        if ( xmlData.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( xmlData.status == 200 ) {
                programme = xmlData.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("programme");
                for ( var programme in programme ) {
                    alert(programme + ": All data has been updated!");
                    // and the rest of the code continue -->
                }
            }
        }
    }
    loadXMLData = function( url ) {
        xmlData = null;
        if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
            xmlData = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
            try {
                xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch( e ) {
                xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        if ( xmlData !== null ) {
            xmlData.onreadystatechange = update;
            xmlData.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlData.send( null );
        }
        else {
            alert("\nYour browser does not support AJAX Request!");
        }
    };
    window.onload = function() { autoUpdate = setInterval('loadXMLData("EXAMPLE_XML_FILE.xml")', 10000); 
    };
    ]]>
```

**target**

I want to refresh the XML file every 1 minute but This process will be automated & without refresh page load

**result**

Why does not work.. There are no errors, only; white error

PS.: I do not have any html code

Comment: Is your code ever executing at all? Have you tried putting an `alert()` in there?

Comment: @Pekka웃 There is no response.. I think I need the HTML codes for print

Comment: Do you have `<script>` tags in your code?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes I have, You can see full codes; http://pastebin.com/tF3pMyna